# Need to insert a string if array returns empty using linq queries

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

Here is my viewModel:

```
private AttachmentViewModel MapAttachmentViewModel(WorkOrderAttachment attachment)
    {

        var fileInfo = _fileService.GetFileInformation(attachment.FileLog);
        return new AttachmentViewModel
        {
            Id = attachment.Id,
            Exists = fileInfo.Exists,
            FileExtension = fileInfo.Extension,
            FileName = fileInfo.FileName,
            Title = attachment.Title,
            Description = attachment.Description,
            UploadedBy = attachment.CreatedBy,
            UploadedDate = attachment.DateCreated,
            **Categories = attachment.CategoryMappings
                .Select(x => x.WorkOrderAttachmentCategory)
                .Select(x => x.Name) 
                .ToArray()** 


        };
    }
```

example:

For Categories, I need to return the names of the categories but if it returns empty or null, I would like it defualted to "uncategorized".

Comment: Hmm - seems like you want one column to return two different datatypes.  I'd instead have another field defined like **CategoriesIsNull = attachment.CategoryMappings == null ? true : false**

Comment: How about `.Select(x => x.Name ?? "Uncategorized") ` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DefaultIfEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.defaultifempty?view=netframework-4.7.2) like this:

```
Categories = attachment.CategoryMappings
                .Select(x => x.WorkOrderAttachmentCategory)
                .Select(x => x.Name).DefaultIfEmpty("uncategorized")
                .ToArray()
```

this will handle the if collection is null (item has no "CategoryMappings") . But if your "x.Name" is empty string or whitespace you must also take care of that in your "Select(x => x.Name)" statement like this:

```
Select(x => x.Name==null || x.Name==String.Empty?"uncategorized":x.Name)
```

Comment: Thanks Tsungur. I actually was able to figure it out on my own and it was exactly as you had provided.

Comment: @NetMage You are right, I avoided IsNullOrEmpty. Your syntax looks more clean but the question required also the handling of emtyp string. The null-coalescing operator does not handle the empty string scenario.